# Why is Airbus' FCOM structure so different from EASA's recommended OM-B structure?

Tags: easa-regulations, airbus, easa

aicraft operators are allowed to publish their own operations manuals part "B" and in the past, have done so. I nrecent years, many operators revert back to "plain old vanilla" FCOM as published by Airbus.

However, the Airbus FCOM is structured as follows:

- FCOM

  - General
  - Systems
  - Procedures

    - Abnormal
    - Normal
    - Special Operations
  - Limitations
  - Temporary Abnormal Behaviours
  - Performance
- MEL
- CDL

Whereas the EASA OM-B recommended structure is as follows:

- 0 General
- 1 Limitations
- 2 Normal Procedures
- 3 Abnormal and Emergency Procedures
- 4 Performance
- 5 Flight Planning
- 6 Mass and Balance
- 7 Loading
- 8 CDL
- 9 MEL
- 10 Survival Equipment
- 11 Emer Evacuation
- 12 Systems

Why do we have these differences? What are the rationales between these different structures? Why do Airbus and EASA not sit together and fix this?

Comment: Note the document OM part B, introduced by EASA OPS 1.045, is the equivalent of FAA [AC 120-71](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_120-71B.pdf). Both are related to operating procedures developed by operators, and aimed to standardize procedures among different aircraft of an operator. Thus not only EASA and Airbus might sit together, but also other manufacturers, other aviation authorities and operators.